# I need a custom hash function for a dataclass that will produce the same hash for two instances of the class if any two of their attributes are equal

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, hash, hashmap

I need a hash function for the following class, similar to the **eq** method already implemented.
The function should return the same hash value for two instances of the class if any of their attributes compare equal, regardless of whether the other attributes are equal or not.

For example, if both instances of the class have equal sin values, then regardless of any of the other attributes, they should produce the same hash.

What is the best way to go about designing something like this?

```
@dataclass
class ID:
    sin: str
    ssn: str
    ftid: str
    corp_id: str

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.sin and other.sin and self.sin == other.sin:
            return True
        if self.ssn and other.ssn and self.ssn == other.ssn:
            return True
        if self.ftid and other.ftid and self.ftid == other.ftid:
            return True
        if self.corp_id and other.corp_id and self.corp_id == other.corp_id:
            return True
        return False
```

I was unable to think of a solution.